# Jpa mapping, order of insert statements

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

There are two entities with bidirectional one-to-one relationship. The User entity - is the owner. Both shared the same primary key of the User entity:
The owner (parent) entity:

```
class User{
    @Id
    @Column
    @TableGenerator(name = USER_GENERATOR_NAME)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = USER_GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private UserSettings userSettings;

    public UserEntityBean(){
       this.userSettings = new UserSettings(this);
    }
}
```

The dependent entity:

```
class UserSettings{
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    public UserSettings(final User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

When I create new User inside transaction and invoke persist on it, I'm getting the error:
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testbd`.`user_settings`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SETTINGS_TO_USER` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`USER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

In sql log I can see that at first the sql insert into user_settings is executed. But foreign key is required to refer to existing record in the users table. 
The question is can I change the order of inserts?

Can I ask JPA provider to insert first user and only then its user_settings?

Comment: Have you tried mappedBy = "userSettings" ?

Comment: @Brovoker, I've tried:
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
private UserSettings userSettings;

The mappedBy, if I understand correctly should be on the owner entity

Comment: Try mappedBy userSettings in stead of user, that should make the FK in the userSettings table right? Thus making it possible to insert user first.

Comment: @Alexandr, can you show your transaction?